# Create Style from SimpleFeatureCollection

Tags: style, java, geotools, sld

Is it possible to create a `Style` from a `SimpleFeatureCollection` and `SimpleFeatureType`.
I noticed that StyleBuilder has,

```
public Style buildClassifiedStyle(SimpleFeatureCollection fc,
                              String name,
                              String[] colors,
                              SimpleFeatureType schema)
```

I'm just not sure where I can find/create `name` and `colors`, and if this is a viable way to generate a style. 
 The main goal is to produce a `StyledLayerDescriptor`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the great joys of open source code is that you can go and look to see what a method does without any need to guess about the programmer's intent.

So [`buildClassifiedStyle`](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/main/modules/library/main/src/main/java/org/geotools/styling/StyleBuilder.java#L1554):

```
    /**
     * given a feature collection and an array of colours build a style with the given number of
     * classes on the named column
     */
    public Style buildClassifiedStyle(
            SimpleFeatureCollection fc, String name, String[] colors, SimpleFeatureType schema)
            throws IllegalFilterException {
        // grab attribute col
        PropertyName value = ff.property(name);
        String geomName = schema.getGeometryDescriptor().getLocalName();
```

Looks like `name` is the name of the attribute you would like to colour things in by. A little further down the [method](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/main/modules/library/main/src/main/java/org/geotools/styling/StyleBuilder.java#L1587):

```
    Color c = this.createColor(colors[0]);
    PolygonSymbolizer symb1 = createPolygonSymbolizer(c, Color.black, 1.0);
```

and a quick check of [`createColor`](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/main/modules/library/main/src/main/java/org/geotools/styling/StyleBuilder.java#L1650) tells us it takes the hexcode of a colour.

```
private Color createColor(String text) {
    int i = Integer.decode("0x" + text).intValue();

    return Color.decode("" + i);
}
```

So `colors` is an array of strings, containing the hexcodes of the colours you want to use.

We always welcome PRs that propose better documentation or Javadoc strings for methods or classes that people find unclear.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130058/discussion-on-answer-by-ian-turton-create-style-from-simplefeaturecollection).